# Differences: JSONP vs GET

Tags: json, wordpress, http, get, jsonp

That's my question, what are the differences between those requests ?

I am having an issue with `get` request I am trying to perform, I am getting the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8100' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.

that `get` request is toward `my-site-url/wp-json/posts`which is a WordPress account. And [this is the method I am using](http://wp-api.org/)

so, someone says, use `jsonp` instead of `get`, but why?

Answer (score 1):

Jsonp is what is used for web APIs that support cross origin resource sharing. The article below gives an example of how to make a request that supports cors. If the webapi is not configured to allow requests from your host you may not be able to make it work without changing the api though.

Web requests that support cors:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Setting up a web api that uses cors:
http://mobile.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/using-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-asp.net-web-api.html

Comment: Look, this is the method I am using http://wp-api.org/, so that ```get``` request is toward ```my-site-url/wp-json/posts``` which is a WordPress account.

Comment: If I were to guess, the web api is configured to allow requests from urbanetradio.com and it probably fails for you while debugging because the request is coming from localhost:8100.  It looks like there is a step in the api documentation where you set the permalink structure including the host name, maybe that is what configured the web api to allow requests from that host.  http://wp-api.org/#rest-api_installation